# BitXor decimal equivalents

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am trying to understand an algorithms that gray code number in a QAM system which use XOR. Can anyone explain what happens in the Decimal world when you bitxor(a,b) is there a decimal implementation or expalnation for this.

Comment: Did you try Googling for "xor tutorial"?

Answer (score 1):

XOR works in binary base and there's no direct relationship to 10-base (decimal) numbers.

However I don't see a connection between gray code numbers and base 10 (decimal). Is it gray or BCD (binary-coded decimal)?

Gray codes are ways to represent integers as binary numbers so that two consecutive integers differ by one bit only. There when bitxor(a,b) and a = b +/- 1, the result has only one bit set.